# Android List view coloring items

Tags: java, android, listview

I have JSON with 2 fields - Name and gender.
I want to color each name to blue if gender is male and to pink if it's a female.

Here is my code

```
ArrayList feedList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();


for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, Object> hm;
    hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    hm.put("id", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id").toString());
    hm.put("gender", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("gender").toString());
    hm.put("name", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString());
    feedList1.add(hm);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(feedList.getContext(), feedList1, R.layout.list,
            new String[] {"id","name"}, new int[] { R.id.personId, R.id.personName }){
        @Override
        public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
            super.setViewText(v, text);
            if (v.getId() == R.id.personName) {

                if (/* how to get gender of this person*/) 
                    v.setTextColor(R.color.female); 
                else
                    v.setTextColor(R.color.male);
            }
        }

    };

    feedList.setAdapter(adapter);
    feedList.setChoiceMode(feedList.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}
```

Tell me please how to add gender to IF statement.

Comment: you nedd to use a custom adapter, and in "getView()" method you test if (gender == male){set male background} else { female background}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do so without creating your own custom Adapter, so you could override getView. Check the following code and use CustomAdapter instead of SimpleAdapter

```
class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Map<String, Object> item = (Map<String, Object>) getItem(position);
        if ("male".equals(item.get("gender").toString())) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.male);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.female);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. thanx. Only one question - how to set textColor instead of backgroundcolor?

Comment: You can use view.findViewById(R.id.name).setTextColor(R.color.male);

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get the String value before using this.. So you have to do this by:

```
String gender = hm.get("gender");
if (gender.equals("male"))
    dosomething;
else
    doAnotherThing;
```

I think you also have to make hm as    final    !!!
I hope it's helpful for you!!

Answer (score -1):

You should override getView method instead of setViewText. But if you have a very big wish to use setViewText, you could set name of your object to something like "thomas&man", than you can divide you string to array of strings with divider "&" and second item of array will be you gender. But better for use is override getView method, this is the correct way.